# Force.com IDE Eclipse Anonymous execution Debug

Tags: apex, eclipse, debugging, force.com-ide

So I have just started using eclipse with the Force.com IDE. I am executing code in the anonymous window and it shows me that the execution was successful. However, I have a System.debug(); line in my code and it does not get outputted on the User Debug logs. I have used all the log levels and nothing shows up. Were can I view my debug logs when I run my code?

Comment: You could try to make the debug statement more important with `System.debug(Logginglevel.ERROR, 'Test');`

Comment: Nothing is still appearing in the user debug logs.

Comment: So did you already create a User Trace Flags for your user? The problem is not, that you don't see the debugs, but you don't even see logs right?

Comment: I have not created a user trace flag. How would I do so?

Comment: go to developer console and enable debug log for you. then retry. I have seen this problem and sometimes it requires Eclipse restart or passage of time